# JSON Sorting by Alphabetical Order

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to output the JSON below to HTML. I have created the object along with the properties for this object however, I am struggling to output this to HTML. Here is what I have so far. Any idea?

```js
var people;

people = [{
    first_name: 'Don Molloy',
    category: 'academic'
  },
  {
    first_name: 'Pat Quill',
    category: 'academic'
  }
];

console.log(people);

var myObj = JSON.parse(people);
document.getElementById("output-people").innerHTML = myObj.name;
```

```html
<p id="output-people"></p>
```

thanks,

Comment: please specify, what you want. order or output or both?

Comment: firstly, i would like to output the properties to a list. After doing that, the next hurdle is to list them alphabetically by 'first_name'. thanks

Comment: First, `people` is an array and not JSON. Secondary, where is the property `name` ?

Comment: There's no "name" property; you're kind of making things you at the moment. I'd take a step back and do a quick search for how to parse and use json in js. Noting that there's no json here so far.

Comment: @weedoze - correct, that should have been property 'first_name' as oppose to 'name'. thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This not `json` Object .its a normal array Object.so remove the `JSON.parse()` .And change the output innerHTML dom like this `myObj[0].first_name`

**Update:**

For all first_name with sort .try this `myObj.map(a=> a.first_name).sort().join(" and ")`

```js
var people;

people = [{
    first_name: 'Don Molloy',
    category: 'academic'
  },
  {
    first_name: 'Pat Quill',
    category: 'academic'
  }
];

people = people.sort((a,b)=> {
var a1 = a.first_name.toLowerCase();
var b1 = b.first_name.toLowerCase();
return a1<b1 ?-1:a1> b1? 1 :0;
})
console.log(people);

var myObj =people;
document.getElementById("output-people").innerHTML = myObj.map(a=> a.first_name).join(" and ")
```

```html
<p id="output-people"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks :-) how would you go about listing all of the 'first_name' properties alphabetically? i.e. Don Molloy and then Pat Quill.

Comment: The property to sort, in the array of objects, is an string.. So, your code will not work correctly

Comment: @Yosvel Quintero - okay, what do you think works best?

Comment: Array of Objects can be sorted given the value of one of their properties: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: @YosvelQuintero .I was updated with sort function ,from object array .

Comment: @prasad perfect, that was my only comment.. You answer is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

As of your question "JSON Sorting by Alphabetical Order" you can first use [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort the array and than populate the `output` variable and also use the `separator` the way you want to show the names in the html.

Code:

```js
const people = [{first_name: 'Don Molloy',category: 'academic'}, {first_name: 'Pat Quill',category: 'academic'}];
const separator = '<br>';

// Sort array of objects by first_name and populate the output with separator
const output = people
  .sort((a, b) => a.first_name.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.first_name.toLowerCase()))
  .map(user => user.first_name)
  .join(separator);

console.log(people);
document.getElementById('output-people').innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<p id="output-people"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON Sorting by Alphabetical Order in JS =>

You can try this way:

```
function compareStrings(a, b) {
  // Assuming you want case-insensitive comparison
  a = a.toLowerCase();
  b = b.toLowerCase();

  return (a < b) ? -1 : (a > b) ? 1 : 0;
}

places.sort(function(a, b) {
  return compareStrings(a.first_name, b.first_name);
})
```